# Strange test of correlation!

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spearman-rho

I had a strange correlation test result between two variables ($y$ = residuals of a linear regression, $x$ = dependent variable).

In RStudio, `cor(y0,x0)`, which answer is `[1] -1.676535e-16`

*Oh, ok, I have almost zero correlation!*

I decided to test that, and discovered `cor.test()` function, for which follows:

`cor.test(y0, x0, method = "s")`

```
    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  y0 and x0
S = 1076, p-value = 0.6623
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
       rho 
-0.1104231
```

If p-value = 0.66 $\Rightarrow$ reject null hypothesis (true rho equal to 0)
$\Rightarrow$ true rho isn't zero

And rho = -0.11. Cool! It seems that $y_0$ and $x_0$ are correlated in some way.

**But I tried another example:**

Again, in RStudio, `cor(y1,x1)`, which answer is `[1] -0.6859127`

```
    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  y1 and x1
S = 1100, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
       rho 
-0.9642857
```

If p-value < 2.2e-16 ~ 0 $\Rightarrow$ accept null hypothesis (true rho equal to 0)

But rho = -0.96

**How can I accept null hypothesis if rho ($\rho$) is nearly -1?**

That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Also, note that `cor(x, y)` is different from `cor(x, y, method = "s")`, which is why you're seeing different estimates of $\rho$ between the `cor()` and `cor.test()` calls.  The default for both `cor()` and `cor.test()` is Pearson correlation.  The argument `method = "s"` makes the function use Spearman correlation.  For more, see, e,g, <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259664/correlation-between-features-pearson-vs-spearman>

Comment: @DanHicks -- I noticed that. The help file suggests that Spearman's or Kendall's tests could be useful for samples with no independent normal distribution. I have a small sample with a different distribution, which seems to be the case. Thank you!

Comment: Just for curiosity: Why to test for correlation between residuals and regressors? The sample correlation is 0 by construction (in a linear model).

Comment: @MichaelM It is "dependent variable" (fitted values), instead of "independent". I'll edit that.

Comment: Equally strange because also this correlation is 0 by construction ;-)

Comment: @MichaelM You're right. I'll try to find the correct question, this must be wrong. You can answer something I should have seen and did not see, really good job! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your interpretation of the p-values exactly backwards. Small p-values (<0.05, generally) mean that you should reject the null hypothesis, meaning your correlation is significantly different from 0. The p-value is telling you that it's very unlikely that you'd observe this much correlation if the null hypothesis (no correlation) was true. Large p-values (>0.05) indicate that you don't have sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis, meaning that you cannot conclude that you have non-zero correlation.

Your first case with near-zero correlation has a p-value of 0.66, meaning you cannot reject the null hypothesis of 0 correlation. Your second case has a significant p-value (close to 0), meaning you should reject the null hypothesis of no correlation, and accept the alternative hypothesis that the correlation is not equal to 0.

Comment: Oh, such a kids mistake... I think I got confused because the test prints "alternative hypothesis", while I had in mind the null hypothesis. Thank you!

Comment: The test output is simply telling you whether the alternative you had is one or two tailed; that's the only reason it mentioned the alternative.

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah, I noticed that latter, when I chose "greater" instead of "two tailed". Thank you anyway.